# Unable to store value in the model instance that has retrieved from model form

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I a m new to django. I have been trying the following:

I have a form that is associated with the model.

Form Name: ContactForm
Model Name : Contact

in view.py

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = ContactForm(request.POST)
    mInstance = form.save()
    mInstance.trackerID = 23232;  **// This value is not being stored in the database?**
    mInstance.save()
```

I have been struggling with quite some time. Kindly advice where i am committing mistake?
I checked with database, trackerID is always empty.

Comment: Could you share your model and form classes please

Answer (score 1):

you should try:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = ContactForm(request.POST)
    mInstance = form.save(commit=False)
    mInstance.trackerID = 23232;
    mInstance.save()
```

Note the `commit=False` parameter.

More info:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method